# P:editor from Primefaces not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, material-design-lite

I have an application made with JSF 2.0, Primefaces 5.2, using MDL: Material Design Lite from Google ([MDL](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html)).  When I put p:editor on my jsf page it's not working: every element on the editor is disabled.  When I inspect the elements, I can see that every div is disabled.

Also, when I first open the page, the editor does not work, but when I press F12 (to see javascript console) and close that tab (console) the editor starts to work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Improved English syntax and grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently , JavaScript MDL interfered with jquery, when load page, the Editor.init() from Jquery was called, then MDL did something that p:edit was disabled. So, I make it:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                PrimeFaces.ab({s: 'id_from_editor', p: 'id_from_editor', u: 'id_from_editor'});
            }, 1000);
        })
    </script>
```

It's working.

Comment: Hey man, I'm trying to do the same thing you're doing, but its not working. You script works fine when I add it to my template, but it doesn't work when added to a composite page. Any clue how o solve this?